# Setting up Subversion on a VM, and accessing it from the host OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, svn, virtualbox

A little preface: I'm a networking n00b, and the reason I'm doing this is simple for learning purposes.

So here's my setup. I have a wirelss router in my house. On my machine I have Windows 7 and I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 in a VM using VirtualBox. I then set the Network to use a Bridged adapter. When I launch the VM, the 2008 machine gets assigned an IP address, and I can then use Remote Desktop from the host Windows 7 os to control the VM. What I'm trying to do is to follow this tutorial: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/subversion/ to get Subversion set up in the VM. I got the svnserve.exe service installed and running, but when I try to open the Repo browser using tortoisesvn it can't connect. I tried accesing the SVN repository from both the guest OS (windows 2008) and the host OS (windows 7) using: svn://myipaddress/ but with no luck. What am I missing? Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention (Thanks Ignacio) I've tried opening ports 3690 and 22, but still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to open port 3690 for `svn`, and port 22 for `svn+ssh`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I opened port 3690. Just tried opening port 22 as well, and still no luck...